# Name and definition of the standard ordering on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: terminology, definition, order-theory, ordered-fields

Is there any name for the standard ordering on the reals? I typically just see descriptors like "the usual ordering", "the typical ordering", or - well - "the standard ordering". But is there any better name for it so that we can avoid ambiguity or misinterpretation? I kinda want to call it something like "the Archimedean ordering".

Also, what is a rigorous way by which to define it. I was thinking something like this:
$$(\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \,\, \& \,\, \forall y > 0), \,\, (x < x+y)$$
But, of course, this leaves one to wonder what "$y>0$" means. It also relies on the ordered set being endowed with the standard addition operator, which is not always the case and also causes us to need to define addition as well. (If you use addition or another operator in your answer, then please create a rigorous definition of what that addition or operator means too).

This has been bothering me for years, but I have only just now decided to ask about it.

Comment: When it's the "usual" or "standard" it's typically called canonical.

Comment: *The usual order(ing) on* $\Bbb R$ is unambiguous; there is no need for another term. How it is formally defined depends greatly on how one chooses to define the reals.

Comment: At some point we need to take *something* as axiomatic: what structure on $\mathbb{R}$ can we work with? If we're given $+$ and $\cdot$, the ordering is definable as $$x\le y\quad\iff\quad\exists z(z\cdot z+x=y).$$ But neither addition nor multiplication is enough on its own: both $(\mathbb{R};+)$ and $(\mathbb{R};\cdot)$ have automorphisms not preserving the ordering. So the second part of your question needs more context to be answerable.

Comment: Meanwhile, if we take as given the rationals and *their* usual ordering, we can construct $\mathbb{R}$ via Dedekind cuts and then the usual ordering on $\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $a\le b$ iff the left part of $a$ is a subset of the left part of $b$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Good point. In that case, we'd (for a few moments) call it the *induced* ordering, until we notice that it os canonical :)

Comment: I mean, it is the intuitive one that we all learn as children, but that does not mean that it "usual" in specific contexts. If I write a book which uses reverse lexicographic order every time, then a reference to the "usual ordering" may mean reverse lexicographic ordering. In any case, I would like it to have an actual name. "Canonical" is not _too_ bad though; it at least implies a canon/official standard or version somewhere.

Comment: @user173897 No, "the usual ordering" never references anything but this one (and anyone who did use it another way would be figuratively yelled at). But if you are worried nonetheless, "standard ordering" or "canonical ordering" are also fine (although they're as likely to be abused - which is to say, not at all).

Comment: So the whole the whole thing pivots on how we define $\mathbb{R}$? Why not call it the Dedekind-induced ordering or something? I would take the Dedekind cut answer as a fine way by which to define it, though.

Comment: The fact that there are order-nonpreserving automorphisms of $(\mathbb{R}, +. \cdot)$ just freaks me out more if we are defining this order via addition and multiplication. But, as I said, Dedekind cuts are fine by me.

Comment: Don't you have the same issue with any structure in mathematics then? Like "the ring of integers", the "ordered set of natural numbers", and so on..?

Comment: Well, a little. But it seems like it is a little more in-my-face this time because, to me, this ordering means something very concrete. Defining addition for rings in a very abstract way is fine because we care about structure rather than the actual answers.

Comment: I get it. It is definitely a sound desire, that of unveiling this familiar ordering.

Comment: All automorphisms of $(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot)$ do preserve the ordering.  There are non-order preserving automorphisms with respect to addition, or with respect to multiplication, but not both.

Comment: Oh, then I am happy. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reals can be defined as *the* (i.e., unique up to unique isomorphism) complete ordered field. So the order is very inherent. Instead of "usual" or "standard", one might therefore refer to it as "canonical" ordering. However, I'd prefer standard. (The fact that the standard ordering has the property of being Archimedian is secondary; similarly, we wouldn't call the standard ordering of N *the* well-ordeing of N, but say that *the* standard ordering is *a* well-order)

We can see that the ordering of $\Bbb R$ is inherent from the fact that we can express it in terms of the field operations:
$$ x\le y\iff \exists z\colon x+z^2=y.$$

Comment: The $z^2$ is just to avoid the issue of defining "$z>0$", right? It is producing a positive without actually saying that it is positive.

Comment: @user173897 Well, nonnegative. But yes. Meanwhile, note that in $\mathbb{C}$ this trick doesn't work ... and indeed there is no "nice" ordering on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: "The reals can be defined as the (i.e., unique up to unique isomorphism) complete ordered field." Do you have a reference for this? I am very surprised.